# Android - When launch the same activity from widget with different extras, how to prevent the same instance show up after returned from HOME button?

Tags: android, android-widget

I have a widget that contains 4 buttons to show 4 stock prices, each of them will launch into the same activity Quote.class to show stock details. In onUpdate(), it will set up the pendingIntent with extras with stock symbol. After I hit button A, it goes to Quote activity that shows stock A. Then I hit the BACK button to the homescreen, Quote activity calls onDestroy() and when I hit button B, stock B will show properly. However, when i hit HOME button after it shows stock A, the Quote activity only calls onStop without calling onDestroy(), then as i hit button B, it will call onStart() and it shows the same instance that shows stock A.

```
RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.etappwidget); 
setQuoteIntent(context, views, R.id.view1, "BAC", 1);
setQuoteIntent(context, views, R.id.view2, "C", 2);
setQuoteIntent(context, views, R.id.view3, "GOOG", 3);
setQuoteIntent(context, views, R.id.view4, "AAPL", 4);

 private static void setQuoteIntent(Context context, RemoteViews views, int viewId, String symbol, int requestCode) {
 Intent i = new Intent(context, Quote.class);
 i.putExtra("SYMBOL", symbol);
 i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK);
 PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, requestCode, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
 views.setOnClickPendingIntent(viewId, pi);
```

}

Originally I thought adding a flag in the Intent should solve this problem. But I have tried
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK or FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY), none of them makes any difference.

So is there any ways to make it work? How can i remove the history stack from HOME button? How can I call onCreate in Quote activity and get new extras when i hit button B? Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- It is normal for `onDestroy` to possibly not get called if you do simple task switching (like holding the HOME button). If you need to do clean-up, it needs to go in `onPause`.
- I believe the problem is that you have a `PendingIntent` that only differs by extra. PendingIntents are cached, so if you use two with the same action and data, they'll overwrite each other. You can circumvent that by giving each some random data. Try passing the symbol in the data rather than through the extra (which is preferred anyway).

Comment: How exactly should I pass data? Do you mean using intent.setData(Uri uri) method?

Comment: Yes. Create your own simple Uri for stocks.

Comment: Is it works for random data? My way to avoid cached pending intents is to use different intent names for different button/widgets.

Comment: I also had to take the extra step of calling ``setIntent(intent)`` in the ``onNewIntent()`` method of my Activity class.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS);
```

Your activity will not be seen in the history stack

Answer (score 1):

```
clickIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
```

> Since: API Level 1  If set, the new activity is not kept in the
>   history stack. As soon as the user navigates away from it, the
>   activity is finished. This may also be set with the noHistory
>   attribute.

This solved the same issue of mine while implementing widget activities.

Answer (score 0):

When you press home, most probably the activity will not be destroyed. It is put to *pause* state in such case. So, I guess your code to initiate the stock view would stationed in **onCreate** rather than **onResume**. So, moving those to **onResume** should solve the problem.

Comment: I have already tried calling getIntent().getStringExtra("Symbol") in onResume instead of onCreate. However, it will still get Symbol A everytime when I click other buttons in widget. Looks like the same extra will stay there. Is there anyway to replace a new extra? Should i do anything in onStop() maybe?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a different Action in your Intent and use the SingleTop or similar flag and override onNewIntent to detect the correct action that should do the trick.  You need to be prepared to handle the intent in onCreate and onNewIntent.