# How to avoid cached pending intents?

Tags: android, caching, android-pendingintent

Given two identical widgets with different data, A and B, when the data for widget A is shown in the activity launched by the widget, the back button is pressed and then widget B is pressed it all works fine.  However, when the data for widget A is shown, the home button is pressed and then widget B is pressed, the data for widget A is still shown.  From [Android - When launch the same activity from widget with different extras, how to prevent the same instance show up after returned from HOME button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4102627/android-when-launch-the-same-activity-from-widget-with-different-extras-how-t) it suggests that my problem is that both `PendingIntents` (for widgets A and B) are the same and differ only in extras and are therefore cached.  I.e. in the extras is the widget id which is the key I need to retrieve all the data for the widget-press action.  One suggestion was to use different data, but I can't seem to get this to work.  Here is the code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, WidgetActivity.class);
intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId);
intent.setData(Uri.withAppendedPath(Uri.parse("droidln://widget/id/"),
               String.valueOf(appWidgetId)));
PendingIntent pendingIntent = 
               PendingIntent.getActivity(context, appWidgetId, intent, 0);
```

Adding the `setData` to the intent produced no difference.  Any ideas on how to fix my problem of cached pending intents?  I've also tried:

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS);
```

and

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

and

```
intent.setAction("actionstring" + System.currentTimeMillis());
```

all to no effect.

Comment: Have you tried changing your last param of PendingIntent.getActivity from 0 to FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT?

Comment: @Ian, perhaps I don't understand it enough, but won't that override other pendingIntents (from other similiar widgets) extras?  I.e. essentially do what I'm trying to avoid?  In any case, it hasn't fixed my problem.

Comment: It will override any PendingIntent that also matches.  Your action should consist of your package name plus an "action" string of some kind plus the widget ID.  That way, if the PendingIntent for a given widget updates, it will update the existing PendingIntent for that widget.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally (!) found the answer I was looking for, and it was as simple as I hoped it would be.  The PendingIntents were getting setup and passed around correctly.  However, I wasn't explicitly doing anything with the new intent.  When the home button is pressed, the activity retains the original intent which launched it.  All I needed to do was overwrite it with the new intent like this in my Activity:

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    setIntent(intent);
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
}
```

Then, the rest of the lifecycle kicks in (including `onResume()` where much of the processing in my Activity takes place) using the new intent, instead of the original one.

Comment: This worked for me! There was not need to set different Data or Action for the Intent, like other posts said, or even setting the FLAG_xxxxxxx parameter.

Answer (score 5):

Try using both of:

1. Different action for pending intents - `intent.setAction("actionstring" + System.currentTimeMillis());`
2. Proper flag - `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` (for your case : `PendingIntent.getActivity(context, appWidgetId, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);`

I'm using this `PendingIntent` style in many applications and it proved to be right.

The sample code I've been using:

```
final ComponentName receiverName = new ComponentName(context, WidgetProvider.class);
Intent doSth = new Intent("REFRESH_ME" + System.currentTimeMillis());
doSth.setComponent(receiverName);
doSth.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, widgetId);
PendingIntent doSthPending = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, doSth, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Comment: thanks, but unfortunately this didn't work for me.  Are any manifest changes required for this stuff?

Comment: Afraid its still not working for me.  Thanks for your answer anyway.